# Connecting to external data sources like sql database and exchange

Tags: sql-server, bdc, external-data

I am looking for the best options on connecting my SharePoint list with external data sources like SQL database and exchange servers to update the contacts list automatically. 
I am using SharePoint 2010. Any suggestions on this.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL databse you have to use BCS,
Can you please what do you mean by contact list ? It is custom list ? If so again you have to use BCS...

http://blog.arjanfraaij.com/2011/07/sharepoint-2010-using-bcs-with-sql.html
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60190/Business-Connectivity-Services-in-SharePoint
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee557243(v=office.14).aspx

Hope this help!!!

Comment: Yes sidhharth its a custom list. Thanks for the links.  I will implement them on my beta site and will follow up if am stuck anywhere. thanks again.

Comment: np...best luck....!!!!